# Receiving visa after entering Thailand

Tags: visas, thailand

as some of you may know, the process to get a visa for Thailand is quite complicated right now. I had to buy my flight tickets before hand but then I wasted some time because their website is not working on Chrome (and I thought it was just broken), they also ask you for document that does not match your situation (but these documents are required to go to the next step)

I requested an STV visa (3x3 months). But it's very likely going to be accepted too late.
I am French so I can enter the country without any visa (I just need a Thailand Pass).

Is it possible to:

1. Enter the country under visa exemption rules
2. Receive my e-visa once I am in the country
3. Stay (3x3 months)

Comment: Not a real response, but... Normally not. Normally, you need to enter the country to "start" your VISA. But probably you can exit and enter using a cheap flight ticket.. maybe.

Answer (score 2):

I would think it's possible... as far as I know, any extra visas you get are added on top of existing visas, so you could enter without a visa and receive a 30-day visa, renew for another 30 days if needed, and whenever you get your STV it would get added to the visas you have already. If not, you could always do visa runs, so it's still worth coming to Thailand!

Comment: Can you do visa runs though? Doesn't that require entering a third country and having to quarantine (even if just a day) upon returning to Thailand?

Comment: Good point... I will ask someone here (in Thailand)

Comment: Yea, I'm quite sure you're right that you can get a longer visa at a (local) immigration office. I don't know the details but I heard of someone getting 90 days at the embassy, then a year visa locally. That was probably early December 2021. I'm also not sure if that's official procedure or if it's because of connections.

Comment: @JJJ Thailand's land borders remain essentially closed, which means you'd have to fly to do visa runs.  The border with Malaysia seems set to open soon though.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I think (some) border points with Laos have just reopened as well. See for example [this article by the Thaiger](https://thethaiger.com/news/regional/laos/laos-and-thailand-agree-to-re-open-border-checkpoints).